# Trying to get inDesign javascript to make text field nonprinting

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

This seems like it should be very simple, but of course it's blowing up on me.

I'm working with Adobe InDesign CS3 on a form and when certain conditions are met I have a text frame that I've labelled in the script label panel as "RUSH" (no quotes in label panel).  that I want to make nonprinting.  So far it looks like this:

```
document.textFrames.item("RUSH").nonprinting = false;
```

and yet whenever I execute that script I get the error 45 "object not valid"

I'm new to inDesign scripting and I've been searching all day for an example or answer but so far nothing.  Any thoughts?  Did I do or miss something super dumb?

UPDATE: to summarize the below answer, what I was missing was .itemByName

The code now functions as intended with the following line:

```
document.textFrames.itemByName("RUSH").nonprinting = false;
```

With the frame tagged in the Scripts Label panel.

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: Is this labelled textframe placed directly 'on' a page, or is it an in-line frame inside another?

Comment: The text frame is directly on the page, and I have changed the code to
    document.textFrames("RUSH").nonprinting = false;

as I had success using the number in square brackets. I would be happy enough to be able to find out how those numbers are assigned or where I can surface that info. Seems almost arbitrary the way those numbers are given out, and they change when I change the document!

Comment: There are no square brackets nor numbers in your post. Do you mean the value of `textFrame.index` or `textFrame.id`? (`index` is the numerical index of the *n* th item in a list of objects; `id` is a document-wide unique identifier for each separate object.) Never minding that; I'm sure your syntax *should* work -- **if** there is an object called (exactly) "RUSH" -- case sensitive, no spaces or return or anything else.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I was able to see results when I used the square brackets and number, but the nature of the project means that I can't rely on those numbers every time, as it seems making or destroying text frames changes the numbers previously assigned to the target frames. As a secondary question/curiousity, I couldn't find an easy way to surface that number, and was resulting to trial and error to find out which number corresponded to which frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in [this thread on the Adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/978023?tstart=0), a poster says: "Use the Script Label panel in CS4 and below, but the Layers panel in CS5 and above."

On CS6, I can get the text frame to be nonprinting by naming it "RUSH" in the Layers Panel, and running this code:

```
var rush = doc.textFrames.itemByName("RUSH");
rush.nonprinting = false;
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, as he *explicitly* states using the Script Label panel in CS3.

Comment: On a lark I decided to try .itemByName("RUSH") in the above code, and wouldn't you know it...?  Success!

Comment: @WinnipegFats: that *is* unexpected. CS3 is 'old news' for me, and I thought there was no difference between it and my daily work-horse CS4 in this behavior. I'll (slightly) edit Evan's answer so I can remove my downvote.